# move constructor and copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-constructor

My understanding is that a move constructor is called if it exists when we return a local object from a function. However, I ran into a situation where the copy constructor was called instead, as shown in the following example in function `foo2()`. Why did that happen?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class tNode
{
public:
    tNode(int b = 10)
    {
        a = b;
        printf("a: %d, default constructor %s() is called at %s:%d \n", a, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    tNode(const tNode& node)
    {
        a = node.a;
        printf("a: %d, copy constructor %s() is called at %s:%d \n", a, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    tNode& operator=(const tNode& node)
    {
        a = node.a;
        printf("a: %d, copy assignment %s() is called at %s:%d \n", a, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    tNode(tNode&& node)
    {
        a = node.a;
        printf("a: %d, move constructor %s() is called at %s:%d \n", a, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    tNode& operator=(tNode&& node)
    {
        a = node.a;
        printf("a: %d, move assignment %s() is called at %s:%d \n", a, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    ~tNode() { printf("a: %d, destructor %s() is called at %s:%d \n", a, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

private:
    int a = 0;
};

tNode foo()
{
    tNode node;
    return node;
}

tNode foo2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<tNode> up = std::make_unique<tNode>(20);
    return *up;
}

int main()
{
    {
        tNode n1 = foo();
        tNode n2 = foo2();
    }

    // we pause here to watch how objects are created, copied/moved, and destroyed.
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is compiled with `g++ --std=c++17 -fno-elide-constructors` 
and the output is:

```
a: 10, default constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:13
a: 10, move constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:31
a: 10, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
a: 10, move constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:31
a: 10, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
a: 20, default constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:13
a: 20, copy constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:19
a: 20, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
a: 20, move constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:31
a: 20, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
a: 20, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
a: 10, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
```

From the output, we know that a copy constructor is called when `foo2()` returns `*up` to initialize a temporary `tNode` object; why did the move constructor not get called instead?

Comment: Can you shorten your example? I can't believe all those lines are relevant.

Comment: I'm currious, why build with `-fno-elide-constructors`?

Comment: Did you build with optimizations enabled or not? That *might* affect whether the compiler chooses to move or copy - just a guess, but worth testing I think.

Comment: `return *up` line calls copy constructor. See also: RVO.

Comment: `return *up` must make a copy - `*up` is not movable-from.

Comment: Your program introduces undefined behavior.  You do not return a reference in functions that are declared to return a reference.  Functions such as `tNode& operator=(const tNode& node)` -- thus nothing can be surmised from your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think this program has UB, since neither `operator=` is ever called.

Comment: @Angew Well in that case, the OP should remove those calls or change them, in case there is another question posted "Why are my operator= calls not working?"

Comment: You really need to work on **m** in [mcve], probably 2/3rd of the code in your example is irrelevant to the question you're asking.

Comment: Why does `foo2()` return a `tNode` rather than a `std::unique_ptr<tNode>`?

Comment: `tNode(int b = 10)` should *probably* be `explicit` unless you actually need/want it to be available for implicit conversions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Presumably, to demonstrate the language behaviour being asked about?

Comment: @Angew UB is not predicated on the code with UB being *called*. As far as I understand from reading the standard, technically speaking, if the code passed to the compiler containes UB *anywhere*, the entire program is without meaning and the compiler is free to whatever it likes in *any* parts of your program - including parts that don't interact with the UB *at all*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl No, that's not quite precise. If control flow never reaches UB, the program must behave as the standard specifies. However, if control flow ever reaches a UB construct, the entire behaviour is undefined, even "before" the construct is reached. That is precisely how the UB-based optimisations operate: Given `*x = 5; if (!x) return 42; return -42;`, the compiler can say "If `x` is null, the code has UB, so I can remove the condition and just assume `x` is not null."

Comment: @JesperJuhl Specifically, regarding the `return` statement, the standard states: "... flowing off the end of a function other than `main` (6.6.1)
results in undefined behavior." If control never flows off the function because the function is never called, there is no UB."

Comment: @Angew that makes sense. Seems I need to go back and re-read some sections of the standard - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
tNode foo()
{
    tNode node;
    return node;
}
```

and

```
tNode n1 = foo();
```

Is responsible for the output of

```
a: 10,  tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:13
a: 10,  move constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:31
a: 10, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
a: 10,  move constructor tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:31
a: 10, destructor ~tNode() is called at testCopyControl.cpp:40
```

And what you see is the default constructor being called and then `node` begin treated as an rvalue in the return statement to move it into the return value and then another move from the return value into `n1`

With

```
tNode foo2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<tNode> up = std::make_unique<tNode>(20);
    return *up;
}
```

The behavior is different as you are not returning a function local object.  `*up` gives you a `tNode&` so the return statement can't treat it as an rvalue.  Since it is an lvalue you have to call the copy constructor to copy it into the return value.  Then, like the first example, the move constructor is called to move the object from the return value into `n2`.

Answer (score 4):

The following code does not implicitly move the constructed object:

```
tNode foo2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<tNode> up = std::make_unique<tNode>(20);
    return *up;
}
```

This is because, however obvious/intuitive it might seem to us, the compiler cannot prove that it is safe to move-from the object contained by `up`. It's forced to return by copy.

You could force it to return by R-value by explicitly casting the object as such:

```
tNode foo2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<tNode> up = std::make_unique<tNode>(20);
    return std::move(*up);
}
```

Comment: I'd just like to note that `return std::move(...)` is usually an antipattern because it may prevent return value optimizations. And in this example it is only as "correct" as the underlying example is pointless.